# How to start services like Apache and MYSQL from cocoa app on Mac OS 10.8?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-mountain-lion, elevated-privileges

I am new developing with Objective-C and Cocoa.
I need to run/stop/restart Apache and Mysql from a Xcode/Cocoa App and I don't know which is the best practise: Using NSTask, using NSAppleScript or what should be used?

Anyway I think that I need admin privileges for that.

Maybe somebody can help me how or where to get starting with this using best practices.

Below it's little of what I already tried:

I also saw this tutorial: http://www.michaelvobrien.com/blog/2009/07/authorizationexecutewithprivileges-a-simple-example/ but the AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges method is deprecated from OS 10.6.

I tried several methods that I find on stackoverflow.com but without any result.

One of the ways I tried is with the following method that I have in a TasksController class:

```
- (BOOL) runProcessAsAdministrator:(NSString*)scriptPath
                 withArguments:(NSArray *)arguments
                        output:(NSString **)output
              errorDescription:(NSString **)errorDescription {

NSLog(@"runProcessAsAdministrator called!");

NSString * allArgs = [arguments componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
NSString * fullScript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", scriptPath, allArgs];

NSDictionary *errorInfo = [NSDictionary new];
NSString *script =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"do shell script \"sudo %@\" with administrator privileges", fullScript];

NSLog(@"shell script path: %@",script);

NSAppleScript *appleScript = [[NSAppleScript new] initWithSource:script];
NSAppleEventDescriptor * eventResult = [appleScript executeAndReturnError:&errorInfo];

// Check errorInfo
if (! eventResult)
{
    // Describe common errors
    *errorDescription = nil;
    if ([errorInfo valueForKey:NSAppleScriptErrorNumber])
    {
        NSNumber * errorNumber = (NSNumber *)[errorInfo valueForKey:NSAppleScriptErrorNumber];
        if ([errorNumber intValue] == -128)
            *errorDescription = @"The administrator password is required to do this.";
    }

    // Set error message from provided message
    if (*errorDescription == nil)
    {
        if ([errorInfo valueForKey:NSAppleScriptErrorMessage])
            *errorDescription =  (NSString *)[errorInfo valueForKey:NSAppleScriptErrorMessage];
    }

    return NO;
}
else
{
    // Set output to the AppleScript's output
    *output = [eventResult stringValue];

    return YES;
}
}
```

Called as following:

```
 TasksController *tasks = [[TasksController alloc] init];
            NSString * output = nil;
            NSString * processErrorDescription = nil;
            BOOL success = [tasks runProcessAsAdministrator:@"/Applications/MyAPP/Library/bin/httpd"
                                              withArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-f /Applications/MyAPP/conf/apache/MyAPP-httpd.conf", @"-k start", nil]
                                              output:&output
                                              errorDescription:&processErrorDescription
                                              ];


            if (!success) // Process failed to run
            {

                // ...look at errorDescription

                    [_lblStatus setStringValue:@"  Apache could not be started!"];
                    [_txtLogs setStringValue:processErrorDescription];
                    NSLog(@"%@",output);
                    NSLog(@"%@",processErrorDescription);


            }
            else
            {

                // ...process output

                    [_lblStatus setStringValue:@"  Hurray Apache running!!"];
                    [_txtLogs setStringValue:output];

            }
```

When I tried the above method the app is popup a small window asking for admin password but after introducing pass it's try to run and I get the following message in console:

```
dyld: DYLD_ environment variables being ignored because main executable (/usr/libexec/security_authtrampoline) is setuid or setgid
```

I also tried using the following methods but without success:

```
-(NSString*)runCommand:(NSString*)commandToRun
{
    NSTask *task;
    task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    [task setLaunchPath: @"/bin/sh"];

    NSArray *arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                          @"-c" ,
                          [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", commandToRun],
                          nil];
    NSLog(@"run command: %@",commandToRun);
    [task setArguments: arguments];

    NSPipe *pipe;
    pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    [task setStandardOutput: pipe];

    NSFileHandle *file;
    file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

    [task launch];

    NSData *data;
    data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];

    NSString *output;
    output = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return output;

}





-(void) runScript:(NSString*)scriptName
{
    NSTask *task;
    task = [[NSTask alloc] init];

    [task setLaunchPath: @"/bin/sh"];

    NSArray *arguments;
    NSString* newpath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"'%@'/%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], scriptName];


    NSLog(@"shell script path: %@",newpath);
    arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:newpath, nil];
    [task setArguments: arguments];


    NSPipe *pipe;
    pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    [task setStandardOutput: pipe];

    NSFileHandle *file;
    file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];

    [task launch];

    NSData *data;
    data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];

    NSString *string;
    string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog (@"script returned:\n%@", string);
}
```

For this last method I have ShellScript folder in my Supporting Files folder that contain scripts like startMysql.sh, startApache.sh ...

startMysql.sh example:

```
# /bin/sh
/Applications/MyAPP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe --port=8889 --socket=/Applications/MyAPP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock --lower_case_table_names=0 --pid-file=/Applications/MyAPP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid --log-error=/Applications/MyAPP/logs/mysql_error_log &
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd look into launchd - official way to manage services in OSX. You can find example on working with launch here: https://github.com/remysaissy/mongodb-macosx-prefspane